# Facebook status update using django

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) for social authentication in my django application. Now I am going to post facebook status from this application.

At first I have created a facebook app from https://developers.facebook.com/. Here are the steps I have followed ,

1. Create new app
2. Display name and namespace is given. Category selected as Games then create app.
3. App settings -> Add platform -> Website -> site url = test1.com:8000 -> save changes.
4. I have also made the application and all its live features available to the general public.

Then I have added ,

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY='****************'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET='**************************'
```

and

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = [
    'publish_actions'
]
```

to settings.py .

When I run this app and start with facebook authentication it displays following popup,

[image]

And when I click on Play now button it successfully redirects to my django app's homepage and post my facebook status,

Here is my code for posting facebook status ,

```
social_user = request.user.social_auth.filter( provider='facebook',)[0]
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(social_user.extra_data['access_token'])
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="here is status messgae")
```

But when another user [other than my facebook account] tries to authenticate this app is displaying popup like this ,

[image]

In first case I have successfully posted my status, But In second case I am [ message in second popup clearly shows that the app doesn't have any access to users wall.]

This is the error I am getting for the second case ,

```
GraphAPIError at /
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action.
```

**My question is that** , Why my app is not able to post on others wall ?

Is there is any bad configuration (or missed something) I did while creating facebook app ?

Or something else I have to add in settings.py.

Comment: Did you read the big red warning in the first dialog? That you have to submit publish_actions if you want to be able to ask people that doesn't have a role on your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app settings are just fine. Actually, facebook recently made some significant changes and introduced v2.0 (learn more about this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog))

So from now on (you can even check the warning in the first dialog)-

> If your app asks for more than than `public_profile`, `email` and `user_friends` it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers.

Only the testers/developers of the app can test the app with other permissions before they are reviewed by facebook.

You can check out the [review documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) for more details.